# Get Laravel Model->save() error code or message

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, error-handling, eloquent

laravel `Model->save()` does not throw database exception and i want to check unique constraint for a column (no primary key or other forign keys).

is there any way to get database error code of message when `Model->save()` return `false`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `QueryException`. to catch any `SQL` syntax or query errors.

`use Illuminate\Database\QueryException`

```
try {

        $model = Model::find($id);
        $model->name = 'joe';
        $model->save();

    } catch (QueryException $e) {

        dd($e->getMessage());

    }
```

Comment: it's for create but need get error when row will update. what's your opinion?

Comment: I update my answer. But the code is the same.
 Inside the `try` put your code in updating or creating your model,

Comment: save method does not throw any database exceptions. https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_save

Comment: you should use  `Model::find($id)->update(['name' => 'test']);` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use column "UNIQUE" in database , then error handle by QueryException.

Answer (score 0):

```html
=> If you have label exists, See below error:
  "Exception message:SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'TEST  GO' for key 'materials_label_unique' (SQL: insert into `materials` (`label`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (TEST GO, 2019-08-27 09:53:47, 2019-08-27 09:53:47)) with code: 23000"

function insertMaterial()
{
    try {
        $material = new Materials;
        $material->label = "TEST GO";
        if( $material->save() ) {
            return "True as a string";
        } else {
            return "False as a string";
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return 'Exception message:' . $e->getMessage() . ' with code: ' . $e->getCode();
    }
}


=> If you'll try to find the non-existing record, See below error:
   "Exception message: Creating default object from the empty value with code: 0"

function insertMaterial()
{
    try {
        $material = Materials::find(1111);
        $material->label = "TEST GO";
        if( $material->save() ) {
            return "True as a String";
        } else {
            return "False as a String";
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return 'Exception message:' . $e->getMessage() . ' with code: ' . $e->getCode();
    }
}
```